# Opening a Report With a Filter

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have table in Access with budget information I use to generate a report.

One of the fields in my table is called "IsActive". It is defined as a Yes/No field in my table properties.

I would like to open the report and only show the lines where the IsActive field = Yes.

I tried the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "BudgetTable", acViewReport, "WHERE IsActive = Yes"
```

and

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "BudgetTable", acViewReport, "WHERE IsActive = 1"
```

In both cases the report is showing all the fields, including where the IsActive is set to No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code supplies the `WHERE` string as the *FilterName* argument of [OpenReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport) ...

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "BudgetTable", acViewReport, "WHERE IsActive = 1"
                       ^             ^                 ^
                       |             |                 |
                  ReportName       View           FilterName
```

Supply it as the *WhereCondition* instead ...

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "BudgetTable", acViewReport, , "IsActive = True"
                       ^            ^        ^               ^
                       |            |        |               |
                 ReportName       View   FilterName   WhereCondition
```

Note the documentation describes the *WhereCondition* as ...

> *"A string expression that's a valid SQL WHERE clause without the word WHERE."*

So make sure to remove `WHERE` from your *WhereCondition* string.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just realised now that I added the WHERE condition in the wrong sequence.
However, I have changed it to your suggestion which makes perfect sense to me but now I am getting a missing operator error. So I am completely stumped.
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't want a WHERE in there the parameter is already for WHERE. You also may want acViewPreview to open it.

Comment: When I run the DoCmd.OpenReport code I get the error. When I run the following the report opens just fine:

DoCmd.OpenReport "BudgetTable", acViewReport

Comment: Thank you Warcupine, that solved my mystery. The code should look as follows:

DoCmd.OpenReport "BudgetTable", acViewReport, , "IsActive = Yes"

Comment: I just fixed the answer to remove `WHERE` from the *WhereCondition* --- Thanks, @Warcupine.  Is it OK, now?

Comment: @HansUp, looks perfect to me